# Proper C++ type for nested list of arbitrary and variable depth?

Tags: python, c++, list, types

I'm trying to port some code from Python to C++. The Python code has a function `foo` that can take nested lists of ints, with variable list depth. For example, these are legitimate function calls to foo:

```
foo([ [], [[]], [ [], [[]] ] ])
foo([1])
foo([ [1], [2, 3, [4, 5]], [ [6], [7, [8, 9], 10] ] ])
```

What should the method signature(s) be for a C++ method that can accept this kind of argument?

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without knowing what `foo` will do with its argument. Is it treating the value as a tree or some sorts? Does it flatten the list immediately? Does it walk the list in some fashion? Can you elide the datastructure and just pass an iterator?

Comment: C++ and Pythons type system are fundamentally different. You'll need a different design instead of merely replacing type by type. Nevertheless interesting question

Comment: based on what foo needs to do, I'm not that sure that the code inside that function will be that easy to produce nor understand.

Comment: Seems recursive variant is needed.

Comment: @Botje It walks the list recursively, handling ints as it goes, and doing additional processing on lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way that's pretty simple to define and use:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct VariableDepthList : std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int> {
private:
    using base = std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int>;
public:
    using base::base;
    VariableDepthList(std::initializer_list<VariableDepthList> v) : base(v) {}
};
```

This is based on the fact that your type is either an `int` or a list of (the same type), adding an initializer_list constructor just for ease of use.

You might want to add some helper function like `is_vector()`/`is_value()` too.

Here is an example using it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(const VariableDepthList& v) {
    // Use like a variant. This is a print function
    if (auto* as_vector = std::get_if<std::vector<VariableDepthList>>(&v)) {
        if (as_vector->empty()) {
            std::cout << "[]";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "[ ";
        bool first = true;
        for (const auto& el : *as_vector) {
            if (!first) {
                std::cout << ", ";
            }
            first = false;

            foo(el);
        }
        std::cout << " ]";
    } else {
        auto* as_int = std::get_if<int>(&v);
        std::cout << *as_int;
    }
}

int main() {
    foo({});
    std::cout << '\n';
    foo({ 1 });
    std::cout << '\n';
    foo({ {}, {{}}, { {}, {{}} } });
    foo( {{1},{2,3,{4,5}},{{6},{7,{8,9},10}}} );
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is so nice and the easiest to use by far. I added another example to it. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Really nice, super clean in both definition and construction

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

// A class containing either a T or a nest<T>
template<class T>
struct nest {
    auto cbegin() const { return d.cbegin(); }
    auto cend() const { return d.cend(); }
    auto begin() const { return d.cbegin(); }
    auto end() const { return d.cend(); }
    auto begin() { return d.begin(); }
    auto end() { return d.end(); }

    std::vector<std::variant<T, nest<T>>> d;
};

namespace detail {
template<class... Ts> // helper type for visitor
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

template<class... Ts> // deduction guide for helper type
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

template<class T>
void foo_helper(const std::variant<T, nest<T>>& n) {
    std::visit(overloaded {
        [](const T& v) { std::cout << v; },
        [](const nest<T>& v) { foo(v); }
    }, n);
};
} // namespace detail

template<class T>
void foo(const nest<T>& list) {
    auto it = list.begin();
    std::cout << '[';
    if(it != list.end()) {
        detail::foo_helper(*it);
        for(++it; it != list.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << ',';
            detail::foo_helper(*it);
        }
    }
    std::cout << ']';
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "[[1],[2,3,[4,5]],[[6],[7,[8,9],10]]] <- what we aim for\n";

    foo(nest<int>{{nest<int>{{1}},
                   nest<int>{{2, 3, nest<int>{{4, 5}}}},
                   nest<int>{{nest<int>{{6}},
                   nest<int>{{7, nest<int>{{8,9}}, 10}}}}}} );
}
```

Output:

```
[[1],[2,3,[4,5]],[[6],[7,[8,9],10]]] <- what we aim for
[[1],[2,3,[4,5]],[[6],[7,[8,9],10]]]
```

Comment: Nice, construction is much cleaner than mine

Comment: @ThomasJohnson Thanks. I am hoping to be able to reduce the braces galore. I may return to wrap my head around it later. I get dizzy just watching it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving it with this data structure:

```
  using tIntList = std::vector<int>;
  using tListOrInt = std::variant<tIntList, int>;

  class VariableDepthList {
   public:
    using tListOfNestedLists = std::vector<VariableDepthList>;
    using tListElement = std::variant<tListOfNestedLists, tIntList, int>;
    explicit VariableDepthList(tListElement _element) : element(std::move(_element)) {};

    tListElement element;
  };
```

and then various overloads of foo which take each of the variant types.

Here's an example, constructing the list `[ [], [[]], [ [], [[]] ] ]`:

```
  using tListOfNestedLists = VariableDepthList::tListOfNestedLists;
  VariableDepthList deep_list(tListOfNestedLists{
      VariableDepthList(tIntList{}),  // [] 
      VariableDepthList(tListOfNestedLists{VariableDepthList(tIntList{})}),  // [[]]
      VariableDepthList(tListOfNestedLists{
          VariableDepthList(tIntList{}), // [] 
          VariableDepthList(tListOfNestedLists{VariableDepthList(tIntList{})}) // [[]]
      })
  });
```