# how do I replace base constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, std-variant

In recent SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70434677/4139593), part of the snippet I'm unable to understand whats happening,

```
struct VariableDepthList : std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int> {
private:
    using base = std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int>;
public:
    using base::base;
    VariableDepthList(std::initializer_list<VariableDepthList> v) : base(v) {}
};
```

`base(v)` is calling `ctor` of base class, if so what is equivalent to without having `using base::base`?

Comment: You don't need the `using base::base;` part to use `base(v)`: the latter is always (independent of the `using` declaration) constructing the base object, The `using` declaration is used to expose the `base` ctors in your `VariableDepthList`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: If `using base::base` part then i see the error. [DEMO](https://www.godbolt.org/z/fj4qbGT3K)

Comment: as I stated: you don't need the `using` declaration to define the ctor. You may need it, depending on your use, to bypass you constructor and directly use the base class's ctor. As you don't have a constructor viable of `std::initializer_list<int>` but `{ 1 }` is an `std::initializer_list<int>`, the constructor of the base class is used directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is equivalent to without having `using base::base`?

You replace it with what `base` is an alias for:

```
struct VariableDepthList : std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int> {
private:
public:
    VariableDepthList(std::initializer_list<VariableDepthList> v) :
        std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int>(v) // was "base(v)"
   {}
};
```

Note though that without `using` the [base class constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant), they will not be accessible to users of `VariableDepthList`.

If you *do* want the base class constructors to be available, without creating the alias `base`:

```
struct VariableDepthList : std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int> {
private:
public:
    using std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int>::variant;
    
    VariableDepthList(std::initializer_list<VariableDepthList> v) :
        std::variant<std::vector<VariableDepthList>, int>(v) // was "base(v)"
   {}
};
```

Comment: I see compilation error for the same. [DEMO](https://www.godbolt.org/z/EefjKz1sf). I thought something beyond just a replacement is happening underneath.

Comment: @TruthSeeker You get a compilation error because you didn't make the base class constructors available. I updated the answer.